# Touch Events in UIScroll View in iPhone

Tags: iphone, events, uiscrollview, touch

I have created scroll view in my view controller and set the buttons in the scroll view. I have set the scroll view between the two images. The buttons are scrolling horizontally. Now i want to enable and disable the images. For Eg: Initially left images are to be hidden, once moving the button horizontally and enable right button and hidden the left button.

How can i write the touch events for the scroll view?.

```
   - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
         NSLog(@"ImagePressed");
      }
```

If i have used this method in my application. But the methods are doesn't called. SO how can i write the touch events when i clicks the scroll view. If i get the touch events, then only i could enable and disable the images. so please help me out?

See my images, (I have set the two images(left arrow and right arrow images)).

I have set the two images in the imageview and I have set the scroll view as subview for the custom view.(Scroll view is not subview for view controller).

```
UIImageView *leftImg;

UIImageView *rightImg;
```

[image]

[image: image 2]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do can be achieved by setting a `delegate` for your `UIScrollView`.
Your view controller could implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods like

```m
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

And

```m
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

and respond appropriately by checking the `contentOffset` property on the scroll view.