# UITableView Scroll event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to detect if mytable view has been scrolled, I tried all touch events like this one:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    //my code
  }
```

but it seems that all touch events don't response to scroll but they response only when cells are touched, moved,...etc

Is there a way to detect scroll event of UITableView ?

Comment: Refer this [Touch Events in UIScroll View in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3603140/1072867)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

If you implement the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol, you can also implement one of the [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate) methods:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

or

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

For example, if you have a property called `tableView`:

```
// ... setting up the table view here ...
self.tableView.delegate = self;
// ...

// Somewhere in your implementation file:
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"Will begin dragging");
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"Did Scroll");
}
```

This is because `UITableViewDelegate` conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`, as can be seen in the documentation or in the header file.

Comment: What about when we have more than one UITableView?

Comment: You should be able to set the delegate of both table views to `self` and then check which one was scrolled using the `scrollView` that is passed. [See here](http://pastebin.com/FzmcYNzv).

Answer (score 9):

These are the methods from `UITableViewDelegate` using `Swift` to detect when an `UITableView` will scroll or did scroll:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have more than one table views as asked by Solidus, you can cast the scrollview from the callback to tableview as UITableView is derived from UIScrollView and then compare with the tableviews to find the source tableview.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {    
        UITableView* fromTableView = (UITableView*) scrollView;
        UITableView* targetTableView = nil;
        if (fromTableView == self.leftTable) {
            targetTableView = self.leftTable;
        } else {
            targetTableView = self.rightTable;
        }
...
}
```

Comment: A small note: in order for the == comparison to work you don't have to cast.