# Run multiple URLRequest in for loop execute one after previous finished

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, urlrequest, urlsession

In my app I have a task in which user will enter the from and to date and the url will fetch the data. Each URL will return large sized `JSON` string from the server.

Problem arises when user enters larger date interval which makes the server to hang. In android version of the app I used `AsyncTask` to done this. In that I split the requests in to multiple if user enters large date interval. I use for loop to fetch data for each day and publish the progress in `onProgressUpdate` after each day task completed.

In swift also I need to use multiple data tasks in a for loop and publish the results.

```
for i in 0 ..< dates.count {
   // Getting response from server //
   let response = getResponse(imei: sImei, date: dates[i])
   parseResponse(response)
}
```

This is how I planned on doing this. But don't know how to implement this.

I saw some suggestions to use `DispatchGroup`. I'm not familiar with that. So please guide me to achieve my task.

Note: Giving large date interval in single dataTask will choke my server. Because, it's a low end server. So I have to query data for individual dates and combine them.

Comment: please read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484281/waiting-until-the-task-finishes/42484761#42484761. It might help you.

Comment: Your request are independent of each other, right? If you're not using the results of one request before you would send off the next one, you're better off running those concurrently and not waiting for a request to finish before starting the next one.

Answer (score 1):

Use Recursion: initially i = 0 .

```
 func callApi( i : Int){

    if(dates.count > i){

   // After Getting response from server //

        self.callApi(i: i + 1)

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a loop to generate NSBlockOperation and use addDependency to the previous operation.

```
var prevOperation
for i in 0 ..< dates.count {

    var operation = NSBlockOperation() {
        // Getting response from server //
        let response = getResponse(imei: sImei, date: dates[i])
        parseResponse(response)
    }

    if(i>0) {
        operation.addDependency(prevOperation)
    }
    prevOperation=operation;
}
```