# Returning value while dispatching to the main thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have a function `func getValue() -> Bool` that's called from a background thread. This is intentional and also required. Now, the `getValue()` needs to execute something on the main thread, in this case it needs to access `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL`, which must be run on the main queue.

This is my current function:

```
func getValue() -> Bool {
    guard let url = URL(string: "someurl") else { return false }
    return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
}
```

**How can I convert that function to a thread safe one, namely to make sure it always runs on the main thread, without**

- calling the function from the main thread to begin with
- refactoring the function to return the value in a closure

I've tried this:

```
// This causes a deadlock, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484670/1531270
func getValue() -> Bool {
    var flag = false

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let url = URL(string: "someurl"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            flag = true
        }
        group.leave()
    }
    group.wait()

    return flag
}
```

and this:

```
// This crashes with EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) dispatch_sync called on queue already owned by current thread
func getValue() -> Bool {
    return DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        guard let url = URL(string: "someurl") else { return false }
        return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
    }
}
```

but neither of them works. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use DispatchGroup, group.enter() ans leave in the above code.

Comment: @vivekDas If you mean like this `func getValue() -> Bool {
    var flag = false

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let url = URL(string: "someurl"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            flag = true
        }
    }

    return flag
}` then that won't work either since the code inside the dispatch async is never executed, as the function has already returned a value.

Comment: Okay, you are not doing any UI activity, so I think without using any main queue you can do this ? Have you tried this ?

Comment: @vivekDas The reason I'm asking this question is because the main thread checker in Xcode pointed this out, and it does make since as I'm calling UIApplication, which is a part of UIKit. It would probably work fine, but I'd like to follow best practices.

Comment: @matt So the crash (which you couldn't reproduce) occurs when I'm dispatching to the main queue from the main queue (yeah, my bad - I said this is called from a background queue but that's not always the case). I added a check for this and it now seems to work. Xcode paused at a main thread check once even in the main queue block, but I haven't been able to reproduce that, so could've just been a glitch. I'll do more testing before accepting an answer.

Comment: "yeah, my bad - I said this is called from a background queue but that's not always the case" Definitely. As I was about to say, it sounds like something is wrong with how you're calling `getValue`. But you _didn't show that code_. You left out the most important piece of the question. — By the way, your `getValue` can check to see that it's being called on the correct thread; maybe you should add that.

Comment: @matt Of course I would've included that code had I deemed it important. I had this false notion that you couldn't call sync on the main thread, so I didn't pay much attention to the crash I was already expecting. Anyway, like I said, I added a thread check and everything seems to be working. Really appreciate your help, but not the tone.

Comment: Right, but "deemed" and "false notion" are key here. "deemed" suggests it's not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and "false notion" suggests it's an [x-y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'm just trying to point out a better way of asking questions.

Comment: @matt You're correct on that, this is not a great question, and I better understand why.

Comment: "which must be run on the main queue" why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't reproduce any issue with your second example. You didn't show how you're calling `getValue`, so I made something up:

```
func getValue() -> Bool {
   return DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        guard let url = URL(string: "testing://testing") else { return false }
        return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
   }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos:.background).async {
        let ok = self.getValue()
        print(ok) // false, the right answer
    }
}
```

There's no "crash", so I would just go with that. When I use the scheme `testing:` I get `false`, and when I change `testing:` to `https:`, I return `true`, so clearly the method call is working.

Comment: Wouldn't DispatchQueue.main.sync cause a deadlock crash?

Comment: In my case i get a crash  EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10756a84c). Got to check `if Thread.current.isMainThread` to prevent crash.

Answer (score 12):

You're looking for a semaphore - try this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    var value: Bool? = nil
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose one", message: "Take your time, I'll wait", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "true", style: .default, handler: { _ in
            value = true
            semaphore.signal()
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "false", style: .default, handler: { _ in
            value = false
            semaphore.signal()
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    semaphore.wait()
    print("Choice: \(value!)")
}
```

Or to use your example from above:

```
func getValue() -> Bool {
    var flag = false
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let url = URL(string: "someurl"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            flag = true
            semaphore.signal()
        }
    }
    semaphore.wait()
    return flag
}
```

Comment: If `getValue()` is called on the main thread you will produce a deadlock.