# On iOS, Will there be race condition for two UIDragItem.itemProvider.loadObject methods?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am implementing dragging and dropping images from, let say, Safari into a collectionView of my own app. I need the both the *UIImage* and *image url* from the dragItem.

The way to get any of them is to use `UIDragItem.itemProvider.loadObject`. But since `loadObject(ofClass:completionHandler:)` runs [asynchronously](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsitemprovider/2888336-loadobject), how can I make sure there will be no race condition with the code below?

(note: the two are in the `performDropWith` func, I want to make sure they execute in order because I need to do work immediately after the second one finishes)

```
var imageARAndURL = [String: Any]()

_ = item.dragItem.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (provider, error) in
    if let image = provider as? UIImage {
        let aspectRatio = image.size.height / image.size.width
        print(aspectRatio)
        imageARAndURL["aspectRatio"] = aspectRatio
    }
}

_ = item.dragItem.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self) { (provider, error) in
    if let url = provider {
        print(url.imageURL)
        imageARAndURL["imageURL"] = url.imageURL
        print(imageARAndURL)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `DispatchGroup` to wait until both tasks are complete and continue the execution with both values. [More info on this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484670/725628)

Comment: @EmilioPelaez - thanks for your answer. I will try that but I am also curious **if** there will be a race condition, it seems that the second loadObject, which is `loadObject(ofClass: URL.self)` would always execute after the first one, which means they seem to happen in order. And I check code sample online and found that people didn't use `DispatchGroup` for that (this is a homework assignment).

Comment: If it's asynchronous then you simply can't guarantee that it will happen in order, so yes, there will be a race condition; it might work correctly every time, or it might fail when you less expect it, or on a different device (like your professor's). There is a concept called "Defensive Programming", where you implement safeguards for errors you haven't encountered yet. If this is an assignment, I would encourage you to implement it with the `DispatchGroup`, worst case scenario is that you learned to use an important tool.