# CMPedometer queryPedometerData() return wrong steps count

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

CMPedometer `queryPedometerData()` method seems to be return wrong steps count. But I am not sure with all device. I think the reason from `M7 motion coprocessor pedometer`, ins't it?

Please check the log bellow:

```
2019-03-28T22:16:43Z | ViewController | line: 147 | Steps 00117  | startDate 2019-03-28 01:00:00 +0000 | endDate 2019-03-28 02:00:00 +0000
2019-03-28T22:16:43Z | ViewController | line: 147 | Steps 00000  | startDate 2019-03-28 05:00:00 +0000 | endDate 2019-03-28 06:00:00 +0000
```

Adding 10 seconds

```
2019-03-28T22:18:39Z | ViewController | line: 147 | Steps 00000  | startDate 2019-03-28 01:00:00 +0000 | endDate 2019-03-28 02:00:10 +0000
2019-03-28T22:18:39Z | ViewController | line: 147 | Steps 00870  | startDate 2019-03-28 05:00:00 +0000 | endDate 2019-03-28 06:00:10 +0000
```

And adding 12 seconds

```
2019-03-28T22:18:08Z | ViewController | line: 147 | Steps 00117  | startDate 2019-03-28 01:00:00 +0000 | endDate 2019-03-28 02:00:12 +0000
2019-03-28T22:18:08Z | ViewController | line: 147 | Steps 00870  | startDate 2019-03-28 05:00:00 +0000 | endDate 2019-03-28 06:00:12 +0000
```

My query:

```
pedometer.queryPedometerData(from: start, to: end) { (pedometerData, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    guard let data = pedometerData else { return }

    allPedometerData.append(data)
    logger("Steps \(String(format: "%05d", data.numberOfSteps.intValue))  | startDate \(data.startDate) | endDate \(data.endDate)")

}
```

Something like that: [CMPedometer queryPedometerData() returning 0 steps when steps exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517678/cmpedometer-querypedometerdata-returning-0-steps-when-steps-exist)

Comment: I have seen this issue popping up on my health insurance fitness app.  When I asked them about it they indicated that Apple has acknowledged a bug in core motion that occasionally results in dropped minute level step data (zero steps when steps certainly exist).  This can be seen in different counts from the HealthKit data.  I have not yet found anything about this from apple.

Comment: For me, sometimes the number of steps goes to very big number. Do you have any any copy of their official acknowledgement about the bug? And what measure do we do to avoid such problem?
One measure could be to check if 'error' variable is not nil.