# Nil response after assigning data from Alamofire request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am attempting to assign the data from my Alamofire request to a dictionary of parameters, but it always shows up as nil.

```
var params = SomeParams()
params.addUserIds([currentUserID, partnerUserID])
params.name = name

Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get)
            .validate()
            .responseData(completionHandler: { (responseData) in
             DispatchQueue.main.async {                                              
                 params.coverImage = responseData.data!  
             }                                                       
})

// NIL RESPONSE
print(params)
```

I know that it's because the Alamofire call is being done in the background so I attempted to call the main thread and assign it. Yet it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Your print is happening before the dispatch can complete.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace how do I print once it's done?

Comment: Put it in the completion handler

Comment: Alamofire requests work asynchronously. Move the `print` line into the `DispatchQueue` closure right after assigning `responseData.data!`

Comment: @butter_baby use completion handler or check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484670/1240676

Comment: If you are wanting to use params outside of the request you will need to use `DispatchGroups`

Answer (score -1):

You need to perform work (like print) in the `completionHandler`. There is no need of `DispatchQueue`

```
var params = SomeParams()
params.addUserIds([currentUserID, partnerUserID])
params.name = name

Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get)
            .validate()
            .responseData(completionHandler: { (responseData) in

                 params.coverImage = responseData.data!  
                 print(params)

})
```

Comment: Actually there is a need for the dispatchqueue, his example above isn't actually setting an image but if he was setting the `UIImage` he will need to do it on the main queue. He may also want the params outside of the request completion so this doesn't resolve that problem

Comment: @Bot: I thought `params` is a model class where `coverImage` is a property name.