# Download image from URL and save it to Core Data swift

Tags: swift, image, core-data

There is I am trying to download image from URL and save it to variable of model. But it's not setting the image. Inside setImage I saw that it's downloading some data. URL's are checked and working. But when I check it for nil it's showing "empty input", "empty output".

```
let inputImage = UIImageView()
    let outputImage = UIImageView()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let inputURL = URL(string: "someURL")
        let outputURL = URL(string: "someURL")
        inputImage.kf.setImage(with: inputURL)
        outputImage.kf.setImage(with: outputURL)
    }
    let coreDataModel = CoreDataModel()
    
    if let inputImageData = inputImage.image?.pngData()
    {  cloudAnalysisModel.input_image = inputImageData  }
    else
    {  print("empty input")  }
    
    if let outputImageData = outputImage.image?.pngData()
    {  coreDataModel.output_image = outputImageData   }
    else
    {  print("empty output")  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not understood how asynchronous programming works. The block or completionHandler (the one that starts with { and ends with }) gets executed after url is called and response is obtained

What I mean to say here is , that block maybe executed at any time and the code after that is executed right away i.e the code from `let coreDataModel` onwards

So it is obvious that both the `inputImageData` and `outputImageData` are going to be null

Now coming to the solutions:

What you could do is:

1. Shift all the code inside the callback block instead of keeping it outside and show the user some progressbar or UI
2. Use `DispatchGroup` which keeps track of the `DispatchQueue` [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484281/waiting-until-the-task-finishes)