# How to return status for extension CallKit IOS to React Native

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions, call-directory-extension

I'm trying return a enable status extension to **React Native** from **Native IOS**. But result i received always is **null**

My code:

```
import Foundation
import CallKit

@objc(CommonFunction)
class CommonFunction : NSObject {

@objc
static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
 return true
}

var extensionStatus: Any? = 
CXCallDirectoryManager.EnabledStatus.unknown

@objc
func checkExtensionStatus(_ resolve : @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject : RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance.getEnabledStatusForExtension(withIdentifier: "com.***.*****.Extension", completionHandler: {
  (status : CXCallDirectoryManager.EnabledStatus, error: Error?) in
  if let error = error {
    print("Error get status extension: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
   resolve(status)
  })
 }
}
```

Looks like i'm having a async problem? how can i return synchronous so **React Native** can get correct result.

I tried this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484670/16986085 but not working

Many thanks!

I'm newbie IOS

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as text,  not an image.

Comment: Do you get the extension working in React Native?

Comment: Hi @AnwerSolangi, RN work fine with extension, I'm resolved above error just because it's asynchronous. Go ahead if you want to work with an RN. Good luck to you !

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick reply, it would be really appreciated if you share a boilerplate or the code that how you managed the extension? or get the status correctly?

Comment: @AnwerSolangi Simply write a synchronous status check function under native IOS, and from RN you call this function

Comment: Using RCTBridgeModule and RCT_EXTERN_METHOD return RCTPromiseResolveBlock