# UIGesture Recognizer for Scrolling?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I was wondering if there is a UIGesture Recognizer for scrolling, like on a tableView?
So, like the second a user starts scrolling on the tableView, the UIGesture Recognizer is triggered? I tried UISwipeGestureRecognizer but that did not do that trick.

I essentially just want to detect when a user starts scrolling on a tableView, and then update a value based on this. Is there anything designed for this purpose in xCode?

*plz help I have spent 3 days on this one thing :)*

thank you so much

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8642723/3172445

Answer (score 0):

you can use scrollview delegate method for that purpose

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == tblview{
        //Do your code here 
    }
}
```